# How do you defeat the two huge snakes that come out of the wall?

Tags: ben-10-alien-force-vilgax-attacks

In *Ben 10: Alien Force – Vilgax Attacks* (Xbox 360), how do you defeat the two huge snakes that come out of the wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This video demonstrates a walkthrough of the boss](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRt9scNBtDQ&feature=related). It seems that you have to wait until one of the snakes opens their mouth, transform into the form that throws fireballs, and attack at this opportune moment; currently my internet is being slow so I will edit this answer if it turns out to be a multiple step procedure as the battle wears on.